# java.lang.nullpointerexception al cargar tabla con imagenes

Tags: java, mysql

Me encuentro en un callejón sin salida y necesito ayuda, mi error es el siguiente. Al cargar una tabla con imágenes desde mi `BD` de datos de `MySQL` me sale

> java.lang.nullpointerexception

y nose cual es su causa o motivo. El método que utilizo para cargar mi tabla es:

```
private void cargarTabla(){
        try {
            Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
            CallableStatement obtenerProductos = miComando.prepareCall("call obtener_productos()");
            ResultSet rs = obtenerProductos.executeQuery();
            //Instanciamos la clase "ImagenTabla" para renderizarla e mostrar las imagenes.
            jTablaProducto.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ImagenTabla());
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            String Titulo[] = {"Nro", "Producto", "Stock", "Precio Costo", "Precio Venta", "Marca", "Descripción", "Categoria", "Proveedor", "Fecha Vecimiento",
            "Meses Restantes", "Dias Restantes", "Imagen"};
            Object[] fila = new Object[rsmd.getColumnCount()];
            modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, Titulo);
            while (rs.next()) {                
                fila[0] = rs.getInt("Nro");
                fila[1] = rs.getString("Producto");
                fila[2] = rs.getInt("Stock");
                fila[3] = rs.getDouble("Precio Costo");
                fila[4] = rs.getDouble("Precio Venta");
                fila[5] = rs.getString("Marca");
                fila[6] = rs.getString("Descripción");
                fila[7] = rs.getString("Categoria");
                fila[8] = rs.getString("Proveedor");
                fila[9] = rs.getDate("Fecha Vecimiento");
                fila[10] = rs.getInt("Meses Restantes");
                fila[11] = rs.getInt("Dias Restantes");
                Blob blob = rs.getBlob(13);
                if (blob != null) {
                    byte[] data = blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length());
                    BufferedImage img = null;
                    try {
                        img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                    }
                    >>>ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon(img);<<<
                    fila[12] = new JLabel(icono);
                }else{
                    fila[12] = "";
                }
                modelo.addRow(fila);
            }
            jTablaProducto.setModel(modelo);
            jTablaProducto.setRowHeight(64);
            ContarFilas();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar obtener los productos:\n"
                    + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

El **`nullpointerexception`** me sale en la linea de `ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon(img);` agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: ese error debe ocurrir porque cuando se crea img es un objeto nulo trata de imprimir el resultado de la variable `data`

Comment: Ten en cuenta que si salta por el catch, img vale null cosa que también haría que saltase el null pointer

Comment: Estas dos líneas: **`ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon(img);  fila[12] = new JLabel(icono);`** **deberían estar dentro del bloque `try`**, después de esto: `img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));`

Comment: **A. Cerdano** `GRACIAS!` Si era eso lo que me estaba faltando, no estaba capturando el error y me salia la Exception. Ya logre arreglarlo gracias a tu ej.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si todo tu preblema es el nullPointer. Puedes evitarlo con un simple if. Incluyo el fragmento de código exacto

```
if(img !=null){
    ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon(img);
    fila[12] = new JLabel(icono);
}else{
    fila[12] = "";
}
```

Como tienes una traza de error, podrás saber cuando no se genera la imagen por un error. A pasar de que `blob` no sea nulo.

Comment: Si, tu respuesta me solucionaba el problema con el `null` también pero mi error era esencialmente que no estaba capturando las excepsiones con el **try catch** porque en mi BD algunos datos almacenados no eran null dentro del campo **Imagen** sino que eran datos de tipo `longblob` cuando deberían de ser **null**, o sea que no allá ninguna imagen almacenada en ese campo, y al querer leerlo en tipo `longblob` sin a ver ninguna imagen me salia la excepsion **nullpointerexception.** Igualmente tu respuesta es valida. Gracias.